# preg_match custom pattern

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to figure out how to make custom pattern to use with preg_match / preg_match_all.

I need to find `[A-Z]{3}[a-z]{1}[A-Z]{3}`, that would be for an example AREfGER.
3 uppercase, 1 lowercase and 3 uppercase.

anyone know how to make a pattern for this?

Answer (score 3):

You can do:

```
if(preg_match('/^[A-Z]{3}[a-z][A-Z]{3}$/',$input)) {
  // $input has 3 uppercase, 1 lowercase and 3 uppercase.
}
```

You can drop the `{1}` as its redundant.

Also make sure you add start anchor `^` and end anchor `$`. Without them even if the pattern is found anywhere in the input, a success will be reported. Example `@AREfGER#`

**EDIT:**

To find all matches in a text you can use `preg_match_all` as:

```
if(preg_match_all('/([A-Z]{3}[a-z][A-Z]{3})/',$input,$match)) {
  // array $match[1] will have all the matches.
}
```

Comment: is it possible to list all matches?

Comment: If you just want to see the matches do this after you made the `preg_match_all()`-call that codaddict suggests: `echo '<pre>';print_r($matches[1]);echo'</pre>';exit;`

Answer (score 2):

As simple as:

```
preg_match('#[A-Z]{3}[a-z][A-Z]{3}#', $some_string);
```

Or if this has to match the string as a whole: Use Start- and End-Anchor

```
preg_match('#^[A-Z]{3}[a-z][A-Z]{3}$#', $some_string);
```